# Apache ignite performing slow in update query and getting fetch too large error

Tags: python, sql-update, ignite

Apache ignite is performing very slow with dataset 300k records and 19 columns when using update query.

error 1:
I am using single node apache ignite with all default memory configuration.
I used pyignite to fort the connection with apache ignite.I used "Order ID" as index.I did not used affinity key.
The query i am using is

query:

```
ALTER TABLE test10k ADD COLUMN sum2 float;

UPDATE test10k AS a
SET sum2 = (SELECT SUM("Units Sold")  FROM test10k AS b
WHERE a."Order ID" = b."Order ID");
```

error 2:
I also encounter "Failed to run reduce query locally.  `General error: "class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Fetched result set was too large" errror when trying to execute some query.`

example query:

```
select "Order Priority",count( distinct "Units Sold")as countd from test10k group by "Order Priority"
```

Please let me know is there anything I can do for optimization

Please let me know is there anything I can do for optimization or any configuration I need to do to speed up the performance